# Distance based push notification from specific point in ios

Tags: ios, push-notification, distance

i want to send  push notification to users who are at a specific distance from a particular point .
if suppose my location is fixed. let us say distance is 3 miles, i want to  send notifications to users who are in 3 miles radius from my location.

now i am able to send push notifications from server side,if my requirement is possible in iOS , guide me with better tutorials,

out of all my device tokens how to know that particular device tokens separately…..

Note:
**the notifications should only delivered to particular users who are at a certain distance from my location not to all users.**

thank you ...

Answer (score 0):

Parse.com has sample code for doing this, but you need to make the required information available yourself as it isn't built in.

Basically, you need to know what location each of the devices is at (or where each user is and what device they are using) and run a filter yourself to get the list of devices that you want to push to. Then push only to those devices.

Comment: thanks for ur reply, i am not using parse.com to send push notifications, is it not possible from my server

Comment: That's fine, but you can look at their documentation without using it. My answer describes what they do anyway...

Comment: we have only device tokens of users, how to know their location from device token ,i think it may be poosible with udid, but we don't have taht of every user

Comment: You should consider releasing an update to your app and offering location based push only to those users who have updated (so the app is uploading location data).

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 possible ways I'd solve the problem.

First is to make your app submit the user's position in every x minutes. This is the easier but less efficient way.

The second, more efficient way is to send a push for all the devices with no message, badge and sound (so a silent push, the user won't know about it) with a custom payload that contains the coordinates of the point you want. Then on the client side, process this message, get the current location of the device and show a local notification if your current position is near to the one you got in the payload.

Comment: Second option does limit you to iOS 7 and I hope you don't have many users / pay much for the notifications ;-)

Comment: i am not getting plz be more specific

Comment: What don't you get about it?

Comment: when we send silent push where we get the coordinates of user

Comment: You send the silent push whenever you want to send a notification to any device. And processing the push means (from now on everything happens client side, so on the device) iOS has a method which gets called when the app receives a push. In that method you read the data from the payload, get the phone's current location by the CoreLocation framework and compare those two.

Comment: Quick other note, the user should have approved use of location services before you start sending them pushes.

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following:

Backend Service(Server)

Knows which device shall be aware of which location.
Delivers the coordinates of the locations to the devices.

Frontend(app)

uses region monitoring.
receive the coordinates and accuracy from server.
one region is one coordinate from the server with accuracy.
fire loval notification if the uses cross the region border.

its only one possible way... you can also trigger the location of
all devices and regions at server side and send remote notifications
to specific devices. a very good example on APNS you will find at 
raywenderlich -> http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1